# iOS cell with dynamic height has bad width

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout

So first what I want. I want to have cell with dynamic height which is changing by lenght of text. Something like in image:

[image: cells in tableView]

As you can see second cell is over the edge.

How I did it? First I have table with layout to edges:

[image: tableView autolayout constraints]

I created custom SwitchCell with own xib file:
[image]

Label has these autolayout settings:

[image: Label autolayout constraints]

And switch these:

[image: Switch autolayout constraints]

In viewDidLoad I set tableView properties:

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: SwitchCellIdentifier, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: SwitchCellIdentifier)
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)

tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
```

And in cellForRowAtIndexPath I have this:

```
...
var cell:SwitchCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(SwitchCellIdentifier) as SwitchCell
cell.titleLabel.text = "Receive payments via multipay and lorem ipsum bla bla"
return cell
```

So what I've done wrong? What should I change or add?

Comment: Could you go into the visual debugger of xcode and show us the hierarchy of the cell? Also do you get any "constraints broken" messages in the log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps set a max-width constraint on the label or a >= constraint from its trailing edge to the superview. Right now, everything horizontal is "Equal" to fixed values. You'd need to limit the label width, use an inequality constraint between it and the Switch, and/or play w/the constraint priority levels to keep the label from expanding. The estimatedRowHeight and automatic dimensions should still let it expand vertically. –

Comment: I don't want to set max-width for label. So I choose add constraint for trailing edge to superview and it works great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So for your label you can arrange auto shrink to minimum font size then you can avoid to disappear when the text is too long. And the problem is that you just give constraints in your xib not from xib to cell therefore it is appears like that and you should make it in code just examine below code it may give you an example how to do that.

```
NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"viewWidth":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:size.width],
                              @"viewHeight":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:size.height]};

    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(yourXibView);

    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[yourXibView]-0-|"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:metrics
                                                                     views:viewsDictionary];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
```

and do not forget to add `yourXibView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` before above code. This code just in objective c but don't worry it has same logic in swift.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing Content Hugging Priority of the label

[image]